# How to apply brake in car in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am a newbie in Libgdx. I have developed a motor car with left and right controls. Everything is fine but I want to stop the car as soon as the key is released. Obviously its hard to stop a fast moving car but still I couldn't control even a bit. I can either go left and right but I couldn't stop the moving car.

Here is my code

```
public class Car extends InputAdapter{

    private Body chassis,leftWheel,rightWheel;
    private WheelJoint leftAxis,rightAxis;
    private float motorspeed=40;

    public Car(World world, FixtureDef chassisFixtureDef, FixtureDef wheelFixtureDef,
                            float x, float y, float width, float height) {
         //chassis
         BodyDef bodydef=new BodyDef();
         bodydef.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;

         PolygonShape chassisShape=new PolygonShape();
         chassisShape.setAsBox(width/2, height/2);

         chassisFixtureDef.shape=chassisShape;

         chassis=world.createBody(bodydef);
         chassis.createFixture(chassisFixtureDef);

         //left wheel

         CircleShape wheelshape=new CircleShape();
         wheelshape.setRadius(height/5f);

         wheelFixtureDef.shape=wheelshape;
         leftWheel=world.createBody(bodydef);
         leftWheel.createFixture(wheelFixtureDef);

         //right wheel
         rightWheel=world.createBody(bodydef);
         rightWheel.createFixture(wheelFixtureDef);

         //left axis
         WheelJointDef axisDef=new WheelJointDef();
         axisDef.bodyA=chassis;
         axisDef.bodyB=leftWheel;
         axisDef.localAnchorA.set(-width/2 *0.75f + wheelshape.getRadius(),
                                  -height/2*1.25f);
         axisDef.localAxisA.set(0,1);
         axisDef.maxMotorTorque=350;
         leftAxis=(WheelJoint)world.createJoint(axisDef);
         axisDef.bodyB=rightWheel;
         axisDef.localAnchorA.x*=-1;
         rightAxis=(WheelJoint)world.createJoint(axisDef);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(keycode) {
            case Keys.D:
                leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
                leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(-motorspeed);
                break;

            case Keys.A:
                leftAxis.enableMotor(true);
                leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(motorspeed);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(keycode) {
            case Keys.D:
                leftAxis.enableMotor(false);
                break;
            case Keys.A:
                leftAxis.enableMotor(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Body getChassis() {
        return chassis;
    }
}
```

Here is my fixture definition

```
BodyDef grounddef=new BodyDef();
FixtureDef groundFixture=new FixtureDef();
FixtureDef wheelFixtureDef =new FixtureDef();

groundFixture.density=5;
groundFixture.friction=.4f;
groundFixture.restitution=.3f;

wheelFixtureDef.density=groundFixture.density*2.5f;
//cz car is gng higher wn startt so gvng wheel nerya density

wheelFixtureDef.friction=70;
wheelFixtureDef.restitution=.4f;

car=new Car(world,groundFixture,wheelFixtureDef, 1, 3, 6, 4);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(new InputAdapter(){

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        camera.zoom+=amount/25f;
        return false;
    }
},car));
```

I could not make the car stop. Please help .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you may you use a wrong scale. Box2D uses MKS (meters, kilograms, and seconds). And you may have used pixels here instead of meters.

```
chassisShape.setAsBox(width/2, height/2);
```

The FAQ of Box2D suggests to use

```
objects [that are] between 0.1 - 10 meters
```

otherwise you can get strange situations.

But I this is not the main issue. The main issue is that you set the motorspeed in your keyDown handler but in your keyUp handler you don't set it to zero. Because the through the setMotorSpeed applied force still remains if you release your key, the car simply will move on. To solve this, you can change your keyDown handler code to this:

```
switch(keycode) {
        case Keys.D:
            leftAxis.enableMotor(false);
            leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(motorspeed);
            break;
        case Keys.A:
            leftAxis.enableMotor(false);
            leftAxis.setMotorSpeed(motorspeed);
    }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then I suggest that you post your enableMotor() method.

See https://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ